# Induced Sequence of a SES of Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have a question about a step in the proof of Prop. 5.2.15 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 184):

[image]

We have the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{F''} \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F} \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F'} \to 0$.

If $s \in \mathcal{F'}(X)$  and $\{U_i\}_i$ is a covering of $X$, why there exist $t_i \in \mathcal{F}(U_i)$ such that $s|_{U_i} = \beta(U_i)(t_i)$?

Or more precisely I know that a ses as above induce ses of stalks in each $x \in X$:

$0 \to \mathcal{F_x''} \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F_x} \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F_x'} \to 0$, and also a ses of global section: $0 \to \mathcal{F''}(X) \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F}(X) \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F'}(X) \to 0$.

But I'm not sure if it induces also following ses for every open $U_i$:

$0 \to \mathcal{F''}(U_i) \overset{\alpha}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F}(U_i) \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{F'}(U_i) \to 0$

wich was obviously required above to find the $t_i$'s.

Comment: This is not true that a short exact sequence of sheaves $0\rightarrow\mathcal{F}'\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}''\rightarrow 0$ induces a short exact sequence of global sections. In fact the long exact sequence in cohomology measures the failure of the right exactness. As Nicolas Hemelsoet proved in his answer, a map $u:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}''$ is surjective iff for every $U$ and every $s\in\mathcal{F}''(U)$ there exist an open covering $U=\bigcup U_i$ and sections $t_i\in\mathcal{F}(U_i)$ such that $u(t_i)=s_{|U_i}$.

Comment: @Roland : thanks for your comment (I didn't noticed the last part of the paragraph in the question) so I edited my answer with a counter-example.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I was writing an answer but you beat me to it ;) I upvoted your answer (my comment is not really necessary now that you have edited your answer)

Comment: @Roland : oh sorry, thanks for the upvote ! And also thanks for the comment, it would be a shame to say nothing about it.

Answer (score 3):

Liu does *not* asserts that for any cover $U_i$ there are such sections, but that there *exist* such cover. Indeed, by definition a sequence of sheaves is exact iff it is exact at every stalk. Now, if $s \in F'(X)$, by exactness at each stalk,for all $x \in X$ there is $t_x$ with $\beta_x(t_x) = s_x$, i.e there is an open $U_x \ni x$, a section $t \in F(U_x)$ with $\beta(t_U)_x = s_x$ : taking the set of all $U_x$ for $x \in X$ give you the cover you were looking for.

Edit : A short exact of sheaves does **not** induces a short exact of global sections, this is precisely why cohomology is made for ! As an example, let us take the exponential sequence $0 \to \Bbb Z \to \mathcal O \to \mathcal O^* \to 0$ on $X = \Bbb C^*$.Notice that  $\text{id}_{\Bbb C^*}$ is a global section of $\mathcal O^*$ but there is no function $g$, with $e^g = id$ (i.e there is no global logarithm on $\Bbb C^*$).